# \addfontfeatures attribute lost after next fontspec command (like \textbf{})

Tags: xetex, fontspec

1. I'm using Linux Libertine font (from system) with `XeTeX.`
2. In the body, I'm using `OldStyle` numerals while I want `Lining` numerals in the tables.
3. I'm typesetting tables that have some cells with `\bfseries` text.

However, the `\addfontfeature` setting is only applied to regular text, but not text that is set in `\bfseries`.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common},Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \addfontfeature{Numbers={Lining}}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll} \toprule
    3 & 3 \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image: numerals in <code>\bfseries</code> still are <code>OldStyle</code>]

### How can I set `\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining}}` to apply to all text in a group?

Comment: Have you read section **7.3 Changing the currently selected features** of the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#page=19) (p 19)?

Comment: @Werner, I have local copies of the packages I frequently use and apparently, my fontspec documentation was from 2012 `v2.2b`. I read section `7.2` there but it didn't help, neither would I be able to solve my problem with `7.3` in the current one.

Comment: Yes. Your problem is referenced there, but there's no apparent solution provide, just a suggestion about a future implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is reproducible without a tabular:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common},Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

1234567890

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}

1234567890

\normalfont 1234567890

\bfseries 1234567890}

1234567890

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the call to `\normalfont` resets the features back to what's stated at the beginning. The `\bfseries` command does `\fontseries{\bfdefault}\selectfont` which nullifies the chosen feature.

My advice is to avoid `\addfontfeatures` whenever possible, even at the cost of some code duplication.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common},Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\mainlining}[Ligatures=Common,Numbers=Lining]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\mainlining

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll}
\toprule
3 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{array,booktabs,fontspec}
 \usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}
 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=Common}
 \begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\libertineLF
 \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll} \toprule
            123 & 31234 \\ \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Instead of loading another package, I prefer to use the fonts from the system. If I remember correctly, there were also some benefits of this over the `\usepackage{libertine}` approach. Though this case here speaks against it. As I prefer @egreg's approach, I'll take his answer.

Comment: The package loads the the same fonts as with `\setmainfont{...}`. But it does more, defining all those font families for lining and so on

Comment: Ah, 620MiB of disk space for `texlive-fontsextra` package (Arch Linux) was probably one of the reasons why I preferred the system font approach. But thanks for pointing that out!